# Excel - How to insert commas into a £ amount when cell is copied

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a body of text that is copied from another cell which has a currency amount taken from another cell eg

`="This amount is "&C52&" in total"` where C51 - £50,000. However, this comes across as £50000 regardless of what the end cell is formatted as.

Is there a way to show this comma separation?
Thank-you!

Comment: Have a look on [`TEXT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c) function.

Comment: Thank-you! This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the formatting of the original cell (hold CTRL and hit 1 to see the dialogue), depending on software version you might need to click on "Custom" (Excel) or "User defined" (Libreoffice) to see the actual formatting definition so that you can COPY IT (Mark the text, hold CTRL and hit C).
2. Go back to where you wish to have the formatting and enclose the reference (`C52`) in a call to `TEXT()` as in:

`...& TEXT(<expression>,"<formatting code>") & ...`

(e.g. `...& TEXT(C52,"#,##0.00 [$SEK];[RED]-#,##0.00 [$SEK]") & ...` )

Comment: Thank-you for this, the TEXT function what was needed, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TEXT function for this:

```
="This amount is £"&TEXT(C52,"00,000")&" in total"
```